QGraphicsTextItem Setting Text Width For Text Centring
I have a QGraphicsTextItem in which later on I will have to use the toHtml function to retrieve the text and its styling (for writing it into a .ASS file). Currently I use setTextWidth() for the QGraphicsTextItem to allow the text to be in the centre. When setting a text width for the QGraphicsTextItem, the text goes to a new line and this doesn't appear on the toHtml function.
I have found a way to make it display on the toHtml function when a new line was made and what text is in that line, however, I don't like this as I want users to be able to type and the QGraphicsTextItem text width expand with it, whilst having the text centred. If there is a way, then a new line won't be automatically made by the setTextWidth and it will work without having to have a function to check every line on every QGraphicsTextItem and adding a <.br> to it.
I tried using the document().contentsChange() function and adjust the size of the setTextWidth() with it but sometimes it decides to work and then it doesn't. The code below shows my attempt on getting the QGraphicsTextItem to change text width as users type:
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsTextItem, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Create the central widget and layout for the window
        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.central_widget)

        # Create QGraphicsView and QGraphicsScene
        self.view = QGraphicsView()
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.view.setScene(self.scene)
        self.view.setSceneRect(0, 0, 400, 300)

        self.editable_text = QGraphicsTextItem()
        self.editable_text.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.TextEditorInteraction)
        self.editable_text.setFlags(QGraphicsTextItem.ItemIsSelectable | QGraphicsTextItem.ItemIsMovable | QGraphicsTextItem.ItemIsFocusable)

        self.editable_text.setHtml(f'<div style="text-align: center;">This is an example TEXT</div>')

        self.editable_text.setTextWidth(self.view.scene().width())
        self.editable_text.adjustSize()

        self.editable_text.document().contentsChange.connect(self.centre_text)
        self.editable_text.setFont(QFont('Arial', 20))

        self.scene.addItem(self.editable_text)


        # Add the QGraphicsView to the layout
        self.layout.addWidget(self.view)

        # Set the central widget of the QMainWindow
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

    def centre_text(self):
        self.editable_text.setTextWidth(self.editable_text.textWidth())
        print(self.editable_text.textWidth())
        self.editable_text.adjustSize()




app = QApplication(sys.argv)
main_window = MyMainWindow()
main_window.resize(800, 500)
main_window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())




Can you clarify the following? "have the text displayed in the centre when a new line is formatted".

When drawing a text I want the text to start typing in the centre of its line, for example we type from left to right, I want to start typing from the centre to the right and have the text moving left. I know the html styling of "Align=Centre" does this but I don't want to set a fix width as it will create new lines and when retrieving the html it doesn't say where the new lines where created.

Unfortunately, the only way to center text is by specifying the text width. This means that you need to work with the contentsChange signal of the text document, compute the optimal width of each text block (considering manual line breaks, which are not new blocks) and try to setTextWidth() from the maximum width.

I also strongly suggest you to let the default implementation take care of drawing, and avoid overriding paint() in this case, unless you really know what you're doing. Specifically, trying to change the document contents within the paint function is a terrible idea, as it leads to recursion: try to add a print() at the beginning of paint() and you'll see that it's continuously called whenever there is a selection.

I really wouldn't like to set a maximum width and do it the way your suggesting as I won't be able to know where a new line was added within the toHtml function of the QGraphicsTextItem, unless there is a way I know that the paint isn't efficient, it was one of my attempts on trying to get it to centre the text but I wasn't able to.

There really is no simpler alternative. Unless you're prepared to take care of the whole painting completely manually (including laying out the whole text), setting the maximum width is the only option you have: you just have to set it dynamically based on the contents change. Passing through the HTML is inappropriate, you must work with the underlying QTextDocument structure. The problem with your attempt is not about efficiency, but accuracy: as said, changing the contents of the document will automatically cause a repaint, therefore you have an unnecessary and inappropriate recursion.

I have a solution to one of the issue I was facing, however if you could show an example on how to implement a dynamically resizing textWidth it would fix both the issues ( knowing when a new line is added and not having a fix size ), thanks

Wait, I'm confused. From your question and early comments it seemed that you need to adapt the text item while editing, but in your current answer it's only done for exporting. While I understand that you may want a similar result for both, how they're achieved is very different in concepts and, partially, result. Besides, you wrote that you didn't want to set a fixed width, but you're doing that instead, so now the reasoning behind that requirement is unclear. I'd suggest you to take your time and rephrase your post, clarifying the needs above and the context in which all this is used.

Sorry, I have updated my post to better match my question. Before I didn't want to set the text width as I was unable to get it to automatically adjust the text width as users added / remove text, however, if there is a way to do it, so the text width doesn't make text go to a new line automatically, please let me know as my attempts haven't been successful.

After trying multiple different things to getting the text to centre, without it creating a new line I found out that you don't even need to set the Text Width to have the text centred you just have to call self.QGraphicsTextItem.adjustSize() whenever the text is changed:
import sys, re
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsTextItem, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QTextOption
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRectF

class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Create the central widget and layout for the window
        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.central_widget)

        # Create QGraphicsView and QGraphicsScene
        self.view = QGraphicsView()
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.view.setScene(self.scene)
        self.view.setSceneRect(0, 0, 400, 300)

        self.editable_text = QGraphicsTextItem()
        self.editable_text.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.TextEditorInteraction)
        self.editable_text.setFlags(QGraphicsTextItem.ItemIsSelectable | QGraphicsTextItem.ItemIsMovable | QGraphicsTextItem.ItemIsFocusable)

        # Set text option to prevent word wrap
        text_option = QTextOption()
        text_option.setWrapMode(QTextOption.NoWrap)
        text_option.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.editable_text.document().setDefaultTextOption(text_option)

        self.editable_text.setPlainText('This is an example TEXT')
        self.editable_text.setFont(QFont('Arial', 20))
        self.editable_text.adjustSize()

        self.editable_text.document().contentsChange.connect(self.adjust_text_width)

        self.scene.addItem(self.editable_text)

        # Add the QGraphicsView to the layout
        self.layout.addWidget(self.view)

        # Set the central widget of the QMainWindow
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)


    def adjust_text_width(self):
        self.editable_text.adjustSize()
        


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
main_window = MyMainWindow()
main_window.resize(800, 500)
main_window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())

